# Typehints on autospecced mock does not match original

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-typing

I would like an autospecced mock to give me the same typehints as i get from my original function, but I cannot make it work. Below is a minimal example of what I am trying to do

```
from __future__ import annotations

import typing
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

import pandas as pd


def func(a: int, c: pd.Timestamp, d: typing.Literal['e', 'f']) -> None:
    pass


func_annotations = func.__annotations__

mock_func = create_autospec(func)


type_hints = typing.get_type_hints(func) # {'a': <class 'int'>, 'c': <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>, 'return': <class 'NoneType'>}

# This I would like to be equal to type_hints 
type_hints_mocked = typing.get_type_hints(mock_func) # {}

# I noticed 'get_type_hints' uses __annotations__ and tried this hack, but to no avail
mock_func.__annotations__ = func_annotations
type_hints_mocked_2 = typing.get_type_hints(mock_func) # NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

How come the mocked function doesn't give me the same typehints and could I somehow get it to?

Comment: [`get_type_hints`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/typing.py#L2246) does some work to obtain appropriate global and local namespaces in which to evaluate the string `'pd.Timestamp'`. This involves the MRO for `func` and `mock_func`, as appropriate, so I suspect the fact that `mock_func` is a `Mock`, not a function, somehow prevents `pd` from appearing in the resulting namespaces.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think you need annotations on an autospecced mock object? Because I cannot think of a case, where that would be useful.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to explain, but let me give it a go: I have a project containing a function which analyses a functions type hints and docstring and provides an appropriate argumentparser. I have a bunch of scripts that are run this way and I would like to be able to test the parsing of arguments without actually calling the underlying function. I can solve it by having one function containing the typehint and docstrings and one doing the actual work (which is then mocked), but I would love to not have to do that.